# Any resource from where free post processing shader codes can be downloaded from?

Tags: xna, hlsl, shader

I'm trying to find some cool post processing shader codes to try out .. Note that I'm just doing this for educational work so there's no copyright infringement that I would be causing, for those wondering .. I just need to see whats possible with it, and so on ..

So far I've only found this website: http://www.facewound.com/tutorials/shader1/ , but the effects here are relatively '2D' in nature (not strictly speaking here) .. I'm looking for some effects which may be used in a first person view .. Here's what I'm particularly interested in:

1. maybe a circular blur (center
   portion is fine but the circle
   around it is not) kind of effect
   maybe ..
2. Maybe something similar
   to the 'Cartoon Rendering' effects
   here:
   http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/postprocessing/postprocessing.html

Comment: Post-processing effects are usually applied to a 2D image of the scene after it is drawn - regardless of whether the scene itself uses 2D or 3D rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too old, but maybe someone want to know...
For the Cartoon Rendering' effect i found an example here:
-http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToonShading&referringTitle=Ejemplos
It's in XNA 2.0 but can be converter to 4.0

-http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/toon-shader